# Как сделать GUI для ОС на nasm и C (си)?

Tags: c, gui, ос, kernel, nasm

Пишу свою ОС ядро было написано по статье https://xakep.ru/2018/06/18/lets-write-a-kernel/. Сейчас проблема в одном как создавать GUI для такой системы? Хотелось бы как в Windows или Linux. Если можно, то, пожалуйста, с примерами кода и объяснением!

Comment: Изучите kolibriOS, там это все есть.

Comment: Спасибо, гляну!

Comment: Наверное, для начала, надо реализовать механизм динамического подключения драйверов устройств. Иначе замучаетесь пересобирать ядро при отладке

Comment: - "как создавать GUI для такой системы?" 
- Ни в одной существующей ОС (кроме Windows) GIU **не** является частью ОС. И это неспроста :-)